# How would I apply this regex rule

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, integer

In Visual Basic .NET (2010) I have this string type that also contains a Visual Basic code. And I'm trying to replace all the integers with CInt(Integer) using "regular expression"

So from:

```
Dim I As Integer = 0
```

To:

```
Dim I As Integer = CInt(0)
```

And this is the regex I intend to use: http://regex101.com/r/rZ4sJ8

```
/\b(\d+)\b/CInt(\1)
```

I just don't know how to apply it. I tried Regex.Replace() and Regex.Matches etc. and nothing seems to do the trick. I either get a blank result or one with nothing even similar to the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET, you need to separate the search pattern from the replacement pattern, like this:

```
Dim input As String = "Dim I As Integer = 0"
Dim pattern As String = "\b(\d+)\b"
Dim replacement As String = "CInt($1)"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, you really understood what I wanted to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you need:

```
    Dim value As String = "Dim I As Integer = 13"
    Dim pattern As String = "\b(\d+)\b"
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, pattern)

    ' Loop over matches.
    For Each m As Match In matches
        ' Loop over captures.
        For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
            ' Replace original string
            value = value.Substring(0, c.Index) + "CInt(" + c.Value.ToString + ")"
        Next
    Next
```

Although I would question why you need to do that replacement in the first place!

Comment: In this case, I need to replace them in the original string which is a little hard to do in case there are classes or subs with integers in their names. Hence the regex.

Comment: I appreciate the help but honestly, that's none of your business regardless. It's very unprofessional to ask that in my opinion. Though the code you provided gave me errors and the regex you edited ruined it.

Comment: I think you might be able to solve your 'problem' another way. If you explain why you need to do this; someone might have a better suggestion on how to go about it (There is no functional difference between what you are finding and what you are replacing it with)